# Multiple Jcarousel

Tags: jquery, controls, jcarousel

I have two JCarousel's on a single page. The controls (prev/next) for the top carousel are controlling the second carousel:

```
<div class="jcarousel2-wrapper">

 <div class="jcarousel2">
  <ul id="quotes">
   <li><img src="assets/Uploads/a.jpg" width="300" height="100" alt=""></li>
   <li><img src="assets/Uploads/b.jpg" width="300" height="100" alt=""></li>
   <li><img src="assets/Uploads/c.jpg" width="300" height="100" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <a href="/assembly/index.php/home-2/#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
 <a href="/assembly/index.php/home-2/#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div>


<div class="jcarousel-wrapper">

 <div class="jcarousel">
  <ul id="wide">
   <li><img src="assets/Uploads/1978506-10152294289342922-1805665805-o.jpg" alt=""></li>
   <li><img src="assets/Uploads/backcoffee-square.png" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <a href="/assembly/index.php/home-2/#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
 <a href="/assembly/index.php/home-2/#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div>
```

I also have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery('.quotes').jcarousel();

        jQuery('#wide').jcarousel({
            vertical: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Alan.

Answer (score 0):

You will, at a minimum have to change the class of your second carousel's prev & next button and update the resulting javascript in jcarousels files.

I would try and avoid putting to carousel's on the same page.

[image: You can see that the a.control-next is what is triggering the function]

Answer (score 0):

There is a **jcarousel control plugin** that will give you this behavior, and duplicated classes should be fine.

Control Plugin setup/example:
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/control/reference/installation.html

Once you're including that plugin on your page, the code should be as simple as:

```
$(function() {
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
        // Core configuration goes here
    });

    $('.jcarousel-control-prev').jcarouselControl({
        target: '-=1'
    });

    $('.jcarousel-control-next').jcarouselControl({
        target: '+=1'
    });
});
```

As long as each set of controls is in a wrapper with it's carousel, it's fairly simple to have multiple jcarousels on one page, even with the same carousel class.